Не отображается документация OpenAPI
Делаю проект по туториалу Litestar.
Написал только

@get("/")
async def hello_world() -> str:
    return "Hello, world!"

app = Litestar([hello_world])

При запуске приложения хэндлер http://127.0.0.1:8000/ работает, но при переходе на страницу документации (http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/swagger или http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/elements и др.) в консоли пишется INFO: 127.0.0.1:66450 - "GET /schema/swagger HTTP/1.1" 200 OK но на странице ничего не отображается. При добавлении хэндлеров ничего не меняется. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Возможно мне необходимо что-то загрузить, потому что всё это происходит на компьютере без интернета.

Подключение к интернету необходимо для того, чтобы открыть swagger документацию. Когда вы открываете страницу /schema/swagger, делаются запросы на https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist@5.1.3/....., чтобы загрузить JS/CSS, которы рисуют UI на основе openapi.json.
В DevTools вы увидите такую ошибку
swagger:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
at swagger:16:28

